# Java - Install an array by another array in

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am a beginner in Java, and I want to do a program to work like this: we have an integer array already initialised, we want to know how many numbers are lower than 5 for example, and if we have 4 numbers lower then 5 we want to get this in the output:

> 4 numbers are lower than 5

This is my code for it and it's a little bit close to it I think, thanks.

```
    int num[] = {2, 8, 9, 4, 1};
    int under[] = {0};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (num[i] < 5) {

            num[i] = under[i];

            System.out.println(num.length + " are under 5");

        }

    }
```

Comment: If you just need the count, why both with a second array?  Just increment an `int` every time you find a value under 5 and then output that `int` value at the end.

Comment: Hint: An array is a data structure that you should use when you need to store multiple objects at once. You however just want to count something and your result will be a single number. There is no need for a second array, just any basic data type that can store a number that you use as a counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java 8 features.

```
    final List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    List<Integer> newList = integers
            .stream()
            .filter((n) -> n < 5)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(newList.size());
```

Comment: This solution is really good, but maybe a bit too complicated if he is a beginner I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change a few things. First you need to write your output outside of you For-loop otherwise it will print you this solution everytime.
Next thing is, you should have a counter and count how many times you save a number in your array "under".
I also intialized the length of under to the length of "num". Because you could have a situation where every number is under 5.

This is how your code should look like:

´´´

```
    int num[] = {2, 8, 9, 4, 1};
    int under[] = new int [num.length];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (num[i] < 5){
            under[count] = num[i];
            count++;
        }

    }
    
    System.out.println(count + " are under 5");
```

´´´

There are probably easier ways to solve it, maybe even without a counter.

Answer (score 0):

All answers I found here are obviously correct, even if I don't understand why everyone all save the numbers found in an another array instead of just count them ...

Anyway I'm writing this for suggest you another way to do the same thing, surely not faster then the others you have already read, but I'm sure that you can use it to learn something:

```
int [] num = {3,5,7,8,2,3,4,1,6,7,8,2,4,3}
Arrays.sort(num);
System.out.printf("There are %d numbers lower then 5", Math.max(0,Arrays.binarySearch(num, 5)));
```